# Can't use variables in inner classes

Tags: java, android, class, compiler-errors, instance

I am currently working on a quiz game in Android Studio and I am having a hard time trying to solve the errors given by the usage of outer class variables in button's OnClickListener inner class. I need to use those variables in order to specify the array index for questions, choices and answers.

Here's the code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class info extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    String [] questionsIT = {
            "When did Windows 10 appear?",
            "When did the first iPhone appear?",
            "Who presented the iPhone 4?",
            "What's the most widely used browser in the world?",
            "Which language is Windows written in?",
            "WHich country did the inventor of PHP language come from?",
            "How many cores does a quad-core processor have?",
            "Which company owns XBOX?",
            "Which company owns PlayStation?",
            "In which american state are the Google headquarters located?"
    };

    String [][] choicesIT = {
            {"1989", "2015", "2002", "2012"},
            {"1999", "2006", "2008", "2007"},
            {"Steve Jobs", "Tim Cook", "Bill Gates", "Steve Wozniak"},
            {"Microsoft Edge", "Internet Explorer", "Google Chrome", "Mozzila Firefox"},
            {"C++", "Pascal", "Java", "Perl"},
            {"Romania", "UK", "Greenland", "Germany"},
            {"2 cores", "4 cores", "6 cores", "8 cores"},
            {"Google", "Sony", "Samsung", "Microsoft"},
            {"Microsoft", "Sony", "Apple", "Nokia"},
            {"New York", "Texas", "Ohio", "California"}
    };

    final String [] answersIT = {
            "2015",
            "2007",
            "Steve Jobs",
            "Google Chrome",
            "C++",
            "Greenland",
            "4 cores",
            "Microsoft",
            "Sony",
            "California"
    };

    int[] picsID = {R.drawable.win10, R.drawable.iphone1, R.drawable.apple};

    RelativeLayout rlinfo = findViewById(R.id.rlinfo);    //se alege layout si se init var pt intrb
    TextView intrbinfo = findViewById(R.id.intrbinfo);
    Button ch1 = findViewById(R.id.ch1);
    Button ch2 = findViewById(R.id.ch2);
    Button ch3 = findViewById(R.id.ch3);
    Button ch4 = findViewById(R.id.ch4);

    final Button[] chooses = new Button[]{ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4};
    for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        intrbinfo.setText(questionsIT[i]);
        chooses[0].setText(choicesIT[i][0]);
        chooses[1].setText(choicesIT[i][1]);
        chooses[2].setText(choicesIT[i][2]);
        chooses[3].setText(choicesIT[i][3]);

        chooses[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(chooses[0].getText().equals(answersIT[i]))
                {
                    Right(v);
                    score++;
                }
            }
        });

    }



}

public void Right(View v)
{

}

public void Wrong(View v2)
{

}

}
```

Comment: You didn't say what errors you received.

Comment: You probably need to use a variable that is `final` or `effectively final`.

Comment: Side bar: Instead of using multiple arrays and matching questions/choices/answer by the index, I would suggest creating a question object that has fields for question, choices, and answers. That way you only need one Array of Questions, and it will be much more clean.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are talking about